# Rails how to cache ActiveRecord and keep code DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

I am using Ruby 2.1.7 and Rails 4.0.2 But I am happy to hear solutions from other versions.

I having some DB tables and I would like cache queries between HTTP requests. I want to accomplish few things:

1. I want to the uses of the Model to feel seamlessly
2. I want to override the default behavior as less as possible
3. Keep the code as DRY as possible
4. Avoid the Poltergeist AntiPattern

There is Lew-Level Caching:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

But what if I want to cache an association and also keep the name of association to make the interface readable?

I can think of 3 way to do that but none seems good enough.

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  attr_accessible :name,:country
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  attr_accessible :name,:cities

  # First Approach
  # Special method. does not override ActiveRecord. But does not work seamlessly
  def cached_cities
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/cities", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      cities.to_a
    end
  end

  # Second Approach
  # Using override. Feels seamlessly but Override the default ActiveRecord behavior
  def cities
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/cities", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      City.where({country: self}).to_a
    end
  end
end

# Third Approach
# I think it is a bit Poltergeist anti-pattern
class CachedCountry
  attr_accessor :cities

  def initialize(country)
    self.cities = Rails.cache.fetch("#{country.cache_key}/cities", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      cities.to_a
    end
  end

end

class CitiesController < BackendController
  def get_usa_cities
    render json: Country.find('USA').cached_cities.first
    # Other way
    render json: Country.find('USA').cities.first
  end
end
```

I want to be able to call Country.find('USA').cities and to have the query cached between HTTP requests. But the cities properties is also defined as has_many association. Is the only option is to do something like Country.find('USA').cached_cities? I prefer that the caching will be encapsulated by the default ActiveRecord behavior

Here are some links that demonstrate 2 of the approaches:

cached_cities -
http://codebeerstartups.com/2014/11/scaling-ruby-on-rails-by-caching-your-database-queries/

CachedCountry - https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecord-caching-and-the-single-responsibility

Comment: Could you be more specific? Gem recommendation is off-topic here and your question is too broad.

Comment: I edited the question. I want to cache an association and also keep the name of association to make the interface readable

Comment: What you mean by _keep the name of association_ ? It's still unclear for me.

Comment: From my examples: I want to be able to call Country.find('USA').cities and to have the query cached between HTTP requests. But the cities properties is also defined as has_many association. Is the only option is to do something like Country.find('USA').cached_cities? I prefer that the caching will be encapsulated by the default ActiveRecord behavior